# Reset web visit counter at 00:00:01 in php

Tags: php, date

Given the below code, how do you change the counter value after every twenty-four hour period? I want to reset the webpage visit counter to `1` after `00:00:01`, and I'd like to not reset anythign manually.

```
            <?php
```

function abc()
{

```
if (file_exists('count2.txt')) 
{
    $fil = fopen('count2.txt','r');
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count2.txt')); 
    echo $dat+5;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('count2.txt','w');
    fwrite($fil, $dat+5);
}

else
{
    $fil = fopen('count2.txt','w');
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
}
}
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
 $now = date("H:i:s");//present time
 $d=mktime(00,00,05);//midnight after which set counter to 1
 $tomtime =date( 'H:i:s',$d);//tomorrow time

 $A = strtotime($now);
 $B = strtotime($tomtime );

 $last_modified = filemtime("count2.txt");
 if ($last_modified<$B) {
//do stuff here for reset
 $fil = fopen('count2.txt','w');
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
    abc();
  }
 else
  {
 //echo $A;
  abc();

  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Set a cron job to reset it

Comment: In the absence of cron, you can check the time stamp of every counted visit.  If the "current" visit is on a different day from the "last" visit, reset the counter before counting it.

Comment: Actually, you just need to record the last time the counter was updated, not store a timestamp for every visit. If the counter was last updated 'yesterday', then start at one again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, there's two options here.

---

#### Option 1 - Cron

As @MarkBaker said, you could just use a cronjob like

```
00 00 * * * echo "0" > count_file.txt
```

The chron string is read as

at the `00` minute of the `00` hour `each` day in `each` month on `each` day of the week, run `echo "0" > count_file.txt`

---

#### Option 2 - PHP Solution

Alternatively, you could check the last write date of your file before reading, and if it's before today, simply set your count to 1.

```
$last_modified = filemtime("count_file.txt");
if ($last_modified < strtotime("today midnight")) {
    //do stuff here for reset
}
```

The second one is probably more portable as you may not always have access to cronjobs, and it keeps all of your relevant code in one spot which is always nice as debugging this later could be confusing if someone is not aware of the cronjob.

Relevant PHP Docs:

- [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) - Gets the file modification time
- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

Comment: Hey I made this code, but its ambiguous.It reset many times.Please check.